# Отправление запросов одним объектом XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript

так как синхронные запросы запрещены в приложения Chrome, я решил сымитировать их следующим образом:

```
function test() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open("GET", "https://some text", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "some text");
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4)
        return;
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
    } else {
        obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        oldPrice = (obj.prices[0].ask + obj.prices[0].bid) / 2;
        console.log(oldPrice);
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

Но запрос отправляется только первый раз, а на второй вылетает ошибка Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED. Неужели с одного объекта можно отправить только один запрос? Как в таком случае получать данные с сервера, если разрешено всего 2 соединения в секунду, а данные могут обновляться чаще чем 2 раза в секунду?

Comment: нужно еще раз вызвать _open_

Comment: действительно. только нужно после open заново прописывать заголовки